# rmmod fail with Device or resource busy message

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've searched the net but still haven't found the answer.
I followed the direction on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=800251.
It compiles ok and I can do insmod. The message is displayed ok.
But when I run rmmod, it fails with "Device or resource busy" message.
I changed the name of the module and insmod, rmmod, the same happens.
I don't know how to forcefully rmmod the module and I also want to know what's causing this 'resource busy' pheonomenon.
Any idea?
I'm using ubuntu and was told the system was installed from the binary image not compiled so my guess is there's some discrepancy in the system.. Is there any problem in the program below?
Thanks in advance.
Chan

```
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init hello_world( void )
{
  printk( "hello world!\n" );
  return 0;
}

static void __exit goodbye_world( void )
{
  printk( "goodbye world!\n" );
}

module_init( hello_world );
module_exit( goodbye_world );
```

Comment: Which kernel version are you using? are you using ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check if you are using a compatible compiler.

The way to check kernel-used compiler version:
`cat /proc/version`

Comment: It was 9 years ago, I tried again on ubuntu 20.04 today and it works fine. (I had to add MODULE_LICENSE ("GPL v2"); to avoid compile error). I gave you a +1 for a good info.

Answer (score 0):

Your program seems correct to me. In fact, it works fine on my system. Can you give any additional information that might help, like your dmesg output when you try to rmmod.